# How can I calculate the total billing cost rom the list of products using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

So I am fetching the information in my JSP page using scriptlet. I need to calculate the total cost of the products .

```
<%
                                    List<Products> listProducts = employeeService.listProducts();
                                    for (Products product:listProducts){
                                %>
                                <tr>
                                  <th><%=product.getProduct_id() %></th>
                                  <td><%=product.getName() %></td>
                                  <td>&#8377; <%=product.getPrice() %></td>
                                  <td><%=product.getCategory() %></td>
                                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="addProduct"></td>
                                </tr>
                              
                                <%} %>
                               
                              </tbody>
                              
                                 <tr><input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="shippingCost">Shipping Cost</label> <input type="number"
                                class="form-control" id="shippingCost">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="totalOrderValue">Total Order Value</label> <input type="number"
                                class="form-control" id="totalOrderValue">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

How do i write a Javascript function for the same as I cannot assign ids to individual products here.

Answer (score 0):

Add the class to `product.getPrice()` td. and iterate through tds.

**JS:**

```
const sum = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".productPrice"))
  .map(priceBlock => priceBlock.innerHTML)
  .reduce(((acc, price) => acc + +price), 0);

console.log(sum)
```